# My user control should only be added to a certain type of control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, windows-forms-designer

How can I make it so that my user control can only be added in a certain type of control (here in my case, specifically [`SplitContainer`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer?view=windowsdesktop-6.0))?

Comment: Intrigued as to why..

Comment: I am working on a control library and for certain cases I need to validate that the control can only be added if its parent is of a certain type. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take care of a few things:

1. Control's toolbox item behavior
2. Control's designer behavior
3. Control's run-time runtime behavior (optional)

When you drop the control from toolbox on a design surface, you should prevent it from being dropped on an undesired control; it's responsibility of [CreateComponents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.design.toolboxitem.createcomponents?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) method of the [ToolBoxItem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.design.toolboxitem?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) class assigned to the control.

After the control added to the design surface (for example in the desired parent), then you need to prevent dragging it over undesired controls; it's responsibility of [CanBeParentedTo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.design.controldesigner.canbeparentedto?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) method of the [ControlDesigner](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.design.controldesigner?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) class assigned to the control.

Finally, you may want to even prevent adding it to undesired controls programmatically at run-time; which in this case, it's responsibility of [OnParentChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.onparentchanged?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=windowsdesktop-6.0) method of the control.

**Example - Limit a control to be hosted only in a SplitterContainer**

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Drawing.Design;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;
```

```
[ToolboxItem(typeof(MyControlToolBoxItem))]
[Designer(typeof(MyControlDesigner))]
public class MyControl : Control
{
    protected override void OnParentChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Parent != null && !(Parent is SplitterPanel))
            throw new Exception("You can add this control only to a SplitterContainer.");
        base.OnParentChanged(e);
    }
}
```

```
public class MyControlDesigner : ControlDesigner
{
    public override bool CanBeParentedTo(IDesigner parentDesigner)
    {
        if (parentDesigner.Component is SplitterPanel)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

```
public class MyControlToolBoxItem : ToolboxItem
{
    protected override IComponent[] CreateComponentsCore(IDesignerHost host,
        System.Collections.IDictionary defaultValues)
    {
        if (defaultValues.Contains("Parent"))
        {
            var parent = defaultValues["Parent"];
            if (parent != null && parent is SplitterPanel)
                return base.CreateComponentsCore(host, defaultValues);
        }
        var svc = (IUIService)host.GetService(typeof(IUIService));
        if (svc != null) 
            svc.ShowError("You can drop this control only over a SplitterContainer.");
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem :) You may also take a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50772584/3110834). Also as a side note, usually such a control needs a bit more design-time support, like designer verbs, take a look at [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50801906/3110834) for an enhanced design-time support.